# Puppeteer delete DOM element and children and free memory

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

In Puppeteer:
Right now i'm removing an element from DOM with the following function (i'm removing items from an infinite scroll):

```
  remove_element = async (element) => {
    //removes element from dom
    await element.evaluate((element) => element.parentNode.removeChild(element), element);
  }
```

This doesn't free memory and i'm getting sessions of one page with over 700mb RAM usage. Is there any alternative to free memory of the elements which i remove from DOM?

Comment: It seems like you want page.evaluate there. You're really not showing enough to make sense of it though.